# Add drawing to a Panel

Tags: java, jpanel, graphics2d

This should be simple enough, yet I can't make it work.

I have two classes, one which should draw a circle, and the other which sets up a frame and panel with a button. On clicking the button, a circle should appear on the frame. I am confused as to why it doesn't appear. It's probably something very simple, sorry.

```
package ballsOnPane;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Display implements ActionListener{

    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton button;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
    }

    public Display() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(800, 500);
        frame.setTitle("Show balls");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel = new JPanel();
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        button = new JButton("New Ball");
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        button.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Ball ball = new Ball(100, 100, 50);
        panel.add(ball);

    }

}
```

and ball class:

```
package ballsOnPane;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Ball extends JPanel{

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int r;

    public Ball(int x, int y, int r){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.r = r;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 =(Graphics2D) g;

        Ellipse2D circ = new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, r, r);
        g2.draw(circ);


        }

}
```

Comment: Are you not able to see at least one of the circles?

Comment: Nope, I have made other similar programs where I managed to get images on the panel, and I have tried to follow the same format, but nothing appears.

Comment: LuxxMiner thank you also, this has helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add components to a visible GUI the basic code is:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate(); // to invoke the layout manager
panel.repaint(); // to repaint the components
```

Otherwise the size of the components added is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint. The same goes for the button. It should be added BEFORE the frame is visible, or you need to do the revalidate()/repaint() as well.

In this case you also have a second problem:

```
frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

First you add an empty panel to the CENTER of the BorderLayout, then when you click the button you add the Ball to the CENTER.

Swing will paint the last component added first. So the ball gets painted and then the empty panel gets painted over top.

Get rid of the panel, it serves no purpose.

Edit:

For some reason I thought you were adding the Ball to the frame instead of the panel when you clicked the button.

My explanation above was correct if you did in fact add the Ball directly to the frame.

However, my explanation is incorrect since your code in the ActionListener does add the Ball to the panel.  The proper explanation is below.

When you add the Ball to the panel, you don't see the Ball because by default a JPanel uses a FlowLayout and the FlowLayout respects the preferred size of any component added to it. You did not implement the `getPreferredSize()` method so the size is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

So if you do implement the `getPreferredSize()` method in your Ball class the Ball will dislay on the panel. Also, you will be able to display a new Ball every time you click on the button.

Comment: Thank you! That makes so much sense now. And fixes so many of my other Java related problems ")

Comment: No no no... KEEP THE PANEL. You really shouldn't be drawing on the frame. The code is correct - it adds the ball to the panel, not to the frame. But the ball has no preferred size specified, so it defaults to zero. Also none of this is being done on the Event thread, so the GUI won't display properly.

Comment: @FredK, no in my suggestion he will be adding the `Ball` panel to the content pane of the frame which is perfectly fine. The content pane of the frame is a JPanel, there is no need to create a second panel.

Comment: @Ash, as FredK has pointed out your Ball class does not override the `getPreferredSize()` method and only displays because you are using a BorderLayout. For proper painting read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step1.html) for better working examples.

Answer (score 0):

As camickr answered, you need to `revalidate()` (or call both `invalidate()` & `validate()`, both will work) and then `repaint()` the panel.

The invalidate method marks the panel as being ''incorrect''; basically marking it for inspection.

Validate performs the layout of the component.

Revalidate does both, however, validate is synchronous whilst revalidate is not.

After you've validated the panel, you'll need to call repaint to redraw that panel.

---

As a side-note, [JavaFX is replacing Swing/AWT](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#6), and in my opinon, is easier to use. You may want to look into it. :)

A short code example to do something similar to what you're currently doing, in JavaFX:

```
public class test extends Application{

Scene scene;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.setBackground(
            new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.ALICEBLUE,null,null)));

    Button begin = new Button("Add Circle");
    begin.setOnAction((ActionEvent e)->{ 
        Circle c = new Circle(200,200,100,Color.RED);
        root.getChildren().add(c);
    });

    root.getChildren().add(begin);

    scene = new Scene(root, 700, 700);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```